# Create new column that takes specific values based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe that takes the value from another column only if certain conditions are met.

Here is an example dataframe:

```
cancer_1_type_m <- c(3,3,3,3,-7,-7,-7,99,4)
cancer_1_type_f <- c(-7,-7,-7,-7,3,3,99,99,99)
cancer_1_year <- c(2001,2003,2004,1997,1987,1999,NA,NA,2001)
cancer_2_type_m <- c(99,99,99,99,99,99,99,3,99)
cancer_2_type_f <- c(99,99,99,99,99,99,3,99,99)
cancer_2_year <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2001,1978,NA)
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

df <- data.frame(id,cancer_1_type_f, cancer_1_type_m, cancer_1_year, 
                    cancer_2_type_f, cancer_2_type_m, cancer_2_year)
```

I would like to create the column df$CANCER_YEAR if either type of cancer is == 3. In which case the value in CANCER_YEAR would be == cancer_x_year.

I have been able to make it so CANCER_YEAR takes one value at a time (ie CANCER_YEAR == cancer_1_year if cancer_1_type ==3), but how do I make it look at multiple columns?

This code I have tried works, but for one at a time only:

```
df$CANCER_YEAR <- ifelse(cancer_1_type_m==3 | cancer_1_type_f==3, 
               df$CANCER_YEAR <- cancer_1_year,0)
df$CANCER_YEAR <- ifelse(cancer_2_type_f==3 | cancer_2_type_m==3,
               df$CANCER_YEAR <- cancer_2_year,0)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I solved my issue by combining all the years in a new column and then using dplyr's coalesce function. I am happy to give more details if anybody needs them.

Comment: This only works if none has both type_1 and type_2 equal to 3

Comment: Hello @Friede, you are right. However, my data is such that if somebody has cancer_1_type =3, they can't have cancer_2_type =3.